# Blender 2.8 morbidly slow

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

Is anyone else experiencing this? Blender 2.8 is really slow during undos and transform operations (changing scaling values manually in the lower left box is very slow across all operations).

Comment: Slow undo in complex scenes was a bug that was fixed in 2.83 and improved in 2.90. As far as transform operations I'm personally not experiencing any slowdowns. Maybe try 2.90.1 and see if your problems persist.

Comment: It has moments when it's ok but it's mostly intolerable. Is blender 2.9 much different (hotkey-wise?)

Comment: No not really, 2.90.1 is great.